# The set of all nilpotent matrices is closed. Is it connected?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Prove that the set of all $n\times n$ nilpotent matrices is a closed set when considered as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ and the metric is the usual euclidean metric. Also if it is connected as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$

Comment: I can't hear you because you are shouting:  all caps?  Why?  Then the imperative-I don't take orders from people who don't pay me.  What have you tried?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: By $\Bbb R^2,$ do you perhaps mean $\Bbb R^{n^2}$?

Comment: i am not shouting, caps because it is the title and i don't want to emphasize anything @Ross Millikan

Comment: yes there was a mistake @Cameron Buie

Comment: Thanks for fixing that.  What have you tried?  Where are you stuck? There seems to be an interaction between nilpotent and distance in $\Bbb R^{n^2}$ because if you perturb a single element in a nilpotent matrix, it may not be nilpotent any more.  Can you use that?

Comment: Going off of Ross's hint: I think you can show that the complement of the set is open by showing that for a non-nilpotent matrix (a matrix with a non-zero eigenvalue), there is some $\epsilon>0$ so that a perturbation less than $\epsilon$ will also not be nilpotent.  Thus, each non-nilpotent matrix is part of an open ball in the non-nilpotent matrices.

Answer (score 14):

Let $\phi(A) = A^n$. $\phi$ is continuous, and the set of nilpotent matrices is $\phi^{-1} \{0 \}$, hence closed.

If $A$ is nilpotent, then so is $\lambda A$ for any $\lambda$. It follows that $A$ is path connected by a straight line to $0$. Hence any two nilpotent matrices are connected by a path through $0$. Hence the set of nilpotent matrices is (path) connected.

Comment: the set of nilpotent matrices is (path) connected is true by the above proof but i am not sure about the closedness proof if the nilpotent matrix has potency n then by the function $\phi$ we can claim that the set of all nilpotent matrix with potency n is a closed set . but in general i can't say anything because counable union of closed set is not closed.@copper.hat

Comment: @SHIBASHIS: I'm not sure what you are referring to. A matrix is nilpotent iff all eigenvalues are zero iff $A^n=0$ (by Cayley Hamilton). The function $\phi$ is continuous, hence the inverse image of any closed set is closed. The set $\{0\}$ is closed. I'm not sure where you are getting the countable union of closed sets from?

Comment: yes a matrix is nilpotent iff $A^{n}=0$, but this n is not unique, n may vary, the smallest n is the potency of the nilpotent matrix.all nilpotent matrix does not have the same potency. so there exist a nilpotent matrix B such that $B^{m}=0$ but $B^{n}~\neq~0$ where $m>n$. so yourans is not complete since $\phi$ depends on $n$. do u got it ?? @copper.hat

Comment: @SHIBASHIS: It doesn't matter if the potency is less than $n$. If $A^n=0$ (where $n$ is the dimension of the space), then $A$ is nilpotent. If $A$ is nilpotent, then $A^n = 0$. Cayley Hamilton guarantees this. Do you see this?

Comment: It the set $\phi^{-1}(0)\backslash \{0\}$ connected? :-)

Answer (score 1):

In comments, Alex Ravsky asks if the set of non-zero nilpotent matrices is connected.

The answer is no if $n=2$. Indeed, in that case, that set is the conjugacy class of $$N=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}.$$
So we have to show that this conjugacy class is not connected. The real conjugacy class of a matrix $M$ is path-connected if and only if the intersection of the commutator of $M$ with $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb R)$ contains an element of negative determinant (if that is not the case, the map from the conjugacy class to $\operatorname{GL}_{n}(\mathbb R)/\operatorname{GL}_{n}^+(\mathbb R)\simeq\{±1\}$ is a continuous map which is not constant). The matrix $N$ is cyclic, so its commutant is $\mathbb R[N]$. The determinant of $a_0 Id+a_1 N$ is $a^2_0\geq 0$. So the conjugacy class of $N$ is not connected.

Over $\mathbb C$ or over $\mathbb R$ if $n$ is odd, the set of non-zero nilpotent matrices is path-connected. In that two cases, the conjugacy class of a nilpotent matrix $M$ is path-connected (in the real case, because $-Id$ commutes with $M$), so it is enough to show that there is a path in the set of non-zero nilpotent matrices from the companion matrix of $X^n$ (the matrix with zero coefficients everywhere except on the small diagonal, and with ones there) to any nilpotent matrices in Jordan normal form. This is easily achieved by letting the desired number of coefficients go to zero on the small diagonal.

Comment: Isn't there no need to consider path-connectedness within a single conjugacy class when  $n\ge4$? E.g. if $D=\operatorname{diag}(1,1,1,-1)$ and $J_k$ denotes a nilpotent block of size $k$, while $DJ_4D^{-1}$ is not path-connected to $J_4$ **within** the conjugacy class of $J_4$, both $DJ_4D^{-1}$ and $J_4$ are path-connected to $J_2\oplus0_{2\times2}$ by shrinking all but the $(1,2)$-th entry to zero.